# why am I getting exception: login failed while trying to log in to mongodb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mean-stack, bitnami

First I logged in as administrator to my mongodb:

```
sudo mongo admin --username root --password XXXXXXXX
```

then I created another user with root role:

```
> use admin 
> db.createUser(
    {
      user: "myuser",
      pwd: "myPassw",
      roles: [ "root" ]
    }
)
```

then I wrote:

```
> db.getUsers()
```

and my user was there:

```
{
    "_id" : "admin.root",
    "user" : "root",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "readWriteAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "userAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "dbAdminAnyDatabase",
            "db" : "admin"
        },
        {
            "role" : "clusterAdmin",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : "admin.myuser",
    "user" : "myuser",
    "db" : "admin",
    "roles" : [
        {
            "role" : "root",
            "db" : "admin"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now when I try to log in:

```
sudo mongo admin --username myuser --password myPassw
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017/admin
2016-02-10T21:23:53.964+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: Authentication failed. :
DB.prototype._authOrThrow@src/mongo/shell/db.js:1395:16
@(auth):6:1
@(auth):1:2

exception: login failed
```

What is the reason of that? I restarted the mongodb process but it didn't help.

=======EDIT:

after following Robbie advice I ran the command without `sudo` and unfortunately this is the result:

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-47-102:~/stack$ mongo admin -u myuser -p myPassw
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017/admin
2016-02-10T21:56:15.615+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:0, reason: errno:13 Permission denied
2016-02-10T21:56:15.615+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server /opt/bitnami/mongodb/tmp/mongodb-27017.sock:27017, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:226:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

Comment: does `db.auth('myuser', 'myPassw')` work when you are logged in as the administrator?

Comment: it returns `1`. Is that good?

Comment: "db.auth() returns 0 when authentication is not successful, and 1 when the operation is successful" looks like the user is good - try connecting to the shell without sudo.

Comment: @Robbie please check my updated question

Comment: sorry, i'm not sure then - could be a bitnami related issue... i don't know much about that tho

Comment: I find it kind of strange that you are connecting via a unix socket and not the port. What happens when you run `mongo -u myuser -p myPassw`? Or `mongo -u myuser -p myPassw --authenticationDatabase admin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution ,

Symbol in password was the issue as i had $ sign , changing password with no symbol worked for me !!

Comment: You need to put your password between single quotes `'pa$$word'`.